# org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 737 [character 738 line 1]

Tags: java, iphone, json

I'm using the org.json.JSONObject to parse some json being sent to my servlet by an iphone. I was stuck for a while by why I would be getting an error message at all. The error message was:

org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 737 [character 738 line 1]

After printing out what I received, I see that the string sent was indeed cut short and stopped mid-json. I can't understand why it would be cut short. There's no limit on String size is there (or at least only a memory limit surely).

Has anyone else had thins error?

Cheers

Joe

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are SENDING the correct string?

Comment: How are you sending it? POST or GET?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

json work well with \n but if you have any other special charachters in your meesage like
\ , @ , & , # etc.. first convert them into their respective HEX value and then send your message.

Comment: can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the HTTP GET method to send data using query parameters, realize that there's a practical limit on the amount of data you can send that way. It's about 2000 characters (varies by server and client). You can easily exceed that when URL encoding a shorter string.

Comment: Thanks Eric and the others for your answers. The answer which I found in the end was that the JSONObject was getting stuck on an ampersand character. Great fun.

Answer (score 2):

Json won't work if received string contain new line character like \n. Try to check for it and escape the character.