# JSONException: Unterminated string

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
JSONObject msgObject = JSONObject.fromObject(msg);
```

I then get a JSONException:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 239 of {...}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

edit:
I create a test.txt file:
`{"source":"a\n"}`
the test method is this:

`Scanner cin = new Scanner(new File("test1.txt"), "utf-8");

JSONObject msgObject = JSONObject.fromObject(msg);`


I got this:
key:source&value:a

Comment: possible duplicate of [org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 737 \[character 738 line 1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853917/org-json-jsonexception-unterminated-string-at-737-character-738-line-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your msg content isn't correct, have you tried verifying your JSON ? You can try here : http://jsonlint.com/

Edit: sorry I presumed you used a JSON String. Here is a quote from API :

```
Creates a JSONObject.
Inspects the object type to call the correct JSONObject factory method. Accepts JSON formatted strings, Maps, DynaBeans and JavaBeans.
```

Is your msg object compatible ?

Comment: Are you sure there is no '\n' or '\r' that could "cut" a string in your JSON ?

Comment: there is a '\n'. but it works well at http://jsonlint.com/. I think the question is now here :(  @Michael Laffargue Easysport.fr

Comment: Well it depends fromObject implementation, I found this one : `if ( c == null || c == '\n' ||  c == '\r') {
                throw new JSONException('Unterminated string');
            }`