# unterminated string error with gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I had been using Gson to transport json objects from appengine to my android client with no problem.
I was using the code below.

server:

```
Query<WaterSupply> q = ofy.query(WaterSupply.class).filter("FdID", fdID)
        .filter("timeUpdated >", lastUpdate);
Gson gson=new Gson();

resp.getWriter().print(gson.toJson(q.list()));
```

client:

```
List<WaterSupply> list=new ArrayList<WaterSupply>();
    String json1 =wsResult.wsResponse;


    JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(json1);

    JsonArray array= json.getAsJsonArray();

    Iterator<JsonElement> iterator = array.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        JsonElement json2 = (JsonElement)iterator.next();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        WaterSupply ws= gson.fromJson(json2, WaterSupply.class);
        //can set some values in contact, if required 
        list.add(ws);
    }//Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface com.jackson.FirefighterLog.shared.WaterSupplyProxy.
    //Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.


    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<WaterSupply>>(){}.getType();
    List<WaterSupply> wsList = (List<WaterSupply>) gson.fromJson(wsResult.wsResponse, listType);
```

I have started using larger objects and had to switch to a streaming parsing implementation because I was getting out of memory errors.  I am now using the following code:

server:
same as above

client:

```
   public static List<WaterSupply> readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        List<WaterSupply> messages = new ArrayList<WaterSupply>();
        reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        WaterSupply message = gson.fromJson(reader, WaterSupply.class);
        messages.add(message);
    }
    reader.endArray();
    reader.close();
    return messages;
}
```

I am assuming this has something to do with newline characters(/n), but I am not sure at this point and not sure how to fix this...Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with GSon, but unterminated errors usually indicate truncation or parser errors (as you note above).  I found others having the same problem, and would encourage you to correct for other possible 'special characters'.  In this post, [org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 737 [character 738 line 1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853917/org-json-jsonexception-unterminated-string-at-737-character-738-line-1), the problem was the ampersand character.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response being sent by your server is being truncated. Changing your server code to do this might help:

```
Writer writer = resp.getWriter();
gson.toJson(q.list(), writer);
writer.close();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion I get the same error.  Server side seems fine, it appears to be an issue with the newline characters.  I have tried replacing "\n" with "\\n" on the server, but I get a deadlineexceeded exception on app engine (takes to long)...